# Implement site wide search with neo4j db using node-neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am using [node-neo4j](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j) to communicate with my [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org). Following `github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template` was a real help to get started. Still learning my way to get things done, I am looking to solve a few issues, I'd appreciate any heads up you give me.

#### Implement site wide search.

We have users indexed with their email id's, and want to index stories/posts by tags or keywords. How do we search across all nodes, do we maintain indices for all nodes of various types, what would be a good approach? Should I go with google to enable this feature? How to index same node with multiple tags/keywords?

#### Specify custom id's for nodes

We are fine with integer indices for nodes, but since these id's can be re-used, we would like to identify nodes with unique id's, Is there a way to make neo4j use uuid's, adding an uid attribute would do but want to avoid having to maintain two id's.

#### Traversing nodes

How do we traverse nodes using node-neo4j, `Cipher-lang` looks like the answer, I am yet to get used to it. Does node-neo4j help do this out of the box?

#### Transactions

I may sound silly, but can I do transactional operations with node-neo4j?

Too many questions, I feel most of my doubts would clear once I get more used to querying the db, but any input from you will give me a headstart.

Comment: If you want transactions, I may suggest you to use neo4j-embedded https://github.com/joewhite86/node-neo4j-embedded. It has support for both, cypher queries (including a query builder) and transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should have broken this up into separate questions. I can answer a couple of them but not all.

Yes, node-neo4j can handle Cypher out of the box, with the `query` method: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/develop/lib/GraphDatabase._coffee#L179. Help with Cypher--you should watch this intro video: http://vimeopro.com/neo4j/webinars/video/48603403

For your uuid, you probably should add a separate attribute to the nodes, and have an index on it--just ignore the regular ids except during transient queries where it's more convenient. As far as I know there's no way to override the incrementing ID--that sure would be nice, though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good answer. For the other two questions, you can use one or any number of indices for anything (an index is just a hash table, and you can index any nodes in any indices), and Neo4j unfortunately doesn't support transactions over the REST API, but 1.8 will introduce mutable operations in Cypher, which will work as transactions.

Comment: Thanks Wes, the cypher video link is really useful, Aseem has included some cypher queries in his template app. I will have to learn it anyway! I will proceed with the REST api's for now, I hope not having transaction support does not hurt. I am still not clear about my other question on search implementation, say I have db of short stories, how do search for a story containing some particular words?

Comment: In another app with `mysql` as database for storage, we have configured `sphinx` to provide search, I was under the impression that  `lucene` here could help me achieve the same.